# Generating a div in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to generate an html div in asp.net.

Since a div is considered as an HtmlGenericControl, I tried using that but don't know how to define the type of control, therefore it always generates a "span".

Any ideas on how I can define it as a div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick Google query gave me this:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define it in your codebehind you can use:

```
HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
//You can now put this control in the children of another control by using
myOtherControl.Children.Add(myDiv); //for example a placeholder or panel
```

In your ASPX page you can also create a div which is accessible in your code behind by using:

```
<div runat="server" ID="DivMyDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This answer deserves something. +1

Answer (score 2):

An `<asp:Panel></asp:Panel>` renders as a `<div></div>`